# Show another navigation child controller without parent

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have such schema of navigation controller:

```
(A)RootVC
    |
    -(B)ChildVC_1
    |    |
    |    -(C)ChildVC_1_2
    |
    -(D)ChildVC_2
```

I need from (C) open (D). I use code in (C):

```
navigationController?.popToViewController(...)
rootVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChildVC_2", sender: nil)
```

And it works correct. Except one issue: First I see (A) and only after that, (D) appears on the screen.

The question is: how to open (D) from (C) without showing (A)?
Also, after that when I use back button from (D) I need to open (A)

Comment: Missing some info, which of A,B,C,D are UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to give each vc a storyboard identifier and load it , then assign the `viewControllers` property of the navigationController

```
let rootVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootId")
let dVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dId")
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([rootVC,dVC],animated:true) // set it to false if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to open (D) from (C) without showing (A)

Push D onto C.

> after that when I use back button from (D) I need to open (A)

Right after the push, call `setViewControllers` to remove B and C from the stack invisibly. You are left with just A and D. The Back button thus will lead from D to A, as there is nothing else on the stack.

[image]